# Information from registration form is not submitted into table in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I do not know why it won't connect I have no ideas. When I try to connect it also tells me it's successfully connected to the mysql its weird please help.

It's been annoying the crap out of me and I really need it to work soon because it is driving me nuts.

```
<?

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 1)
    {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, that username is taken. Please go back and try again.</p>";
        $checkemail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."'");

        if(mysql_num_rows($checkemail) == 1)
        {
           echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
           echo "<p>Sorry, that email is taken. Please go back and try again.</p>";
        }
        }
        else
        {
           $registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, EmailAddress) VALUES('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."')");
           if($registerquery)
           {
               echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
               echo "<p>Your account was successfully created. Please <a href=\"login.php\">click here to login</a>.</p>";
           }
           else
           {
               echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
               echo "<p>Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.</p>";    
           }       
       }
    }
    else
    {
?>

<h1>Register</h1>

<p>Please enter your details below to register.</p>

    <form method="post" action="register.php" name="registerform" id="registerform">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username"     id="username" /><br />
        <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password"     id="password" /><br />
        <label for="email">Email Address:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email"    /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>

    <?php
    }
    ?>

Mysql Connected Successfully

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'UNKNOWN_USER'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/parap00per/public_html/register.php on line 28
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/parap00per/public_html/register.php on line 28
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'UNKNOWN_USER'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/parap00per/public_html/register.php on line 29
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/parap00per/public_html/register.php on line 29
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'UNKNOWN_USER'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/parap00per/public_html/register.php on line 30
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/parap00per/public_html/register.php on line 30
Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'UNKNOWN_USER'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/parap00per/public_html/register.php on line 32
Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/parap00per/public_html/register.php on line 32
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/parap00per/public_html/register.php on line 34
Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'UNKNOWN_USER'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/parap00per/public_html/register.php on line 48
Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/parap00per/public_html/register.php on line 48
Error

Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Far as I can tell from your edit, you're not selecting a DB. There's no sign of [`mysql_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)

Comment: I just got tons of errors to this

Comment: What are they? Put them in your question as an edit.

Comment: Btw i just got rid of the mysql database info because it was confidential sorry

Comment: Yes I know that, but you need to select your database by using `mysql_select_db` and it's not anywhere in your old edited code. Are you not using that?

Comment: ?

$host="localhost"; // Host name.
$db_user=""; // MySQL username.
$db_password=""; // MySQL password.
$database=""; // Database name.
$link = mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password);
if (!$link) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
echo "Mysql Connected Successfully";
}
 
mysql_close($link);
?>

Comment: You need to add `$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $link);` and `if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}`

Comment: do i just add that above the db info?

Comment: Read the manual here => http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php - `$db_selected = mysql_select_db('your_db', $link);`

Comment: foo? what does that mean?

Comment: That's just an example.

Comment: ok so give me the code i need to input and tell me where i ned to input it please

Comment: See my answer below, it will be easier for you to see.

Comment: didnt work more errors on different lines now

Comment: I've edited my answer with "You're also closing your connection prematurely using `mysql_close($link);`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not selecting a database with [`mysql_select_db()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php).
(as per your original posted code which was edited).

Replace the `xxx` with your own information.

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name.
$db_user="xxx"; // MySQL username.
$db_password="xxx"; // MySQL password.
$database="xxx"; // Database name.

$link = mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password);
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use the DB : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

You're also closing your connection prematurely using `mysql_close($link);` place it after you've finished querying, or don't use it at all. Your connection will close anyway once it's finished executing.

**Edit:**

I noticed you're using `EmailAddress` and `email` as column names. One of them or others may not be correct.

---

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

---

Also, use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Comment: alright well that made all the errors not display is there anything i am missing

Comment: @Xxcoder14xX What errors are you getting now? Or, what problems are there?

Comment: Well the the error reporting does not display anymore but the problem still remains my registration info is not being submitted to the database.

Comment: Sure, but I noticed you're using `EmailAddress` and `email` as column names. One of them or others may not be correct. @Xxcoder14xX